# Нужно сделать чтобы transition попапа работал и при открытии и при закрытии

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Нужно сделать чтобы transition попапа работал и при открытии и при закрытии, но у меня получилось сделать только при открытии, при закрытии по какой то причине не работает.

```
//Css
.setting-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s, padding .5s;
}
._setting-active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 5em 10em 2em 10em;
  background: rgba(16, 15, 13, .8);
}
```

```
//JS
const setting_btn = document.querySelector('.menu__setting');
const setting_menu = document.querySelector(".setting-menu");
const setting_closed = document.querySelector('.setting-menu__closed');

setting_btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    setting_menu.classList.add("_setting-active");
});
setting_closed.addEventListener("click", function(){
    setting_menu.classList.remove("_setting-active");
});
```

Comment: `visibility: hidden` встает до начала анимации, поставьте вместо него `pointer-events: none`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Не помогло, на сколько я понял нужно было заменить `visibility: hidden` на `pointer-events: none` и `visibility: visible` на `pointer-events: auto` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле у вас всё получилось, если вы следовали комментарию **[@ArtemGorlachev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150290/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-transition-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8#comment1992896_1150290)**, но вы сделали не всё:

1. резко пропадало при "закрытие" потому что `background` был прописан только в момент "активности", а в "обычном состояние" его не было, из-за чего был эффект резкого пропадания блока.
2. Позицию лучше прописывать заранее, то есть в "обычное состояние", т.к. при снятии "активности" позиция будет выставлена по дефолту.

```js
const setting_btn = document.querySelector('.menu__setting');
const setting_menu = document.querySelector(".setting-menu");
const setting_closed = document.querySelector('.setting-menu__closed');

setting_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setting_menu.classList.add("_setting-active");
});
setting_closed.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setting_menu.classList.remove("_setting-active");
});
```

```css
.setting-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s, padding .5s;
  background: rgba(16, 15, 13, .8);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

._setting-active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 5em 10em 2em 10em;
}

.menu__setting,
.setting-menu__closed {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.menu__setting {
  background: green;
}

.setting-menu__closed {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__setting"></div>
<div class="setting-menu__closed"></div>
<div class="setting-menu"></div>
```